# How to call a function after all clicks are finished whether it is a single click or after 10 clicks in rapid secession?

Tags: javascript

I have plus and minus quantity buttons on cart page like 
https://codepen.io/nevcanuludas/pen/WbNbow

I want to call a function to update price based on quantity after user has completed all the clicks.

i.e if user has made a single click only then call the function or if users makes 10 clicks in rapid secession then call the function once ,meanwhile letting user see the quantity is updating after every click in input box

Edit:
Let me rephrase, if user clicks once and after 500 ms the function call is made, but before 500ms if user clicks then he should be allowed update quantity and after 500ms then functions is called

```
var count = 1;
var countEl = document.getElementById("count");
function plus(){
    count++;
    countEl.value = count;
}
function minus(){
  if (count > 1) {
    count--;
    countEl.value = count;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to add a button for 'Submit' or 'Done' or something? How can you guarantee a user has finished clicking?

Comment: How does someone click 10 times simultaneously?  Do you mean in rapid succession?  They would need 10 mice.

Comment: I'm not aware of anyway to do this efficiently. Your best bet is to debounce the call to update the price. If you're using any frameworks in your project, I would check if they have support for debounce. Otherwise you can [add your own](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function). However, before doing any of that. I would really reconsider if this is necessary at all.

Comment: If you just compute the price, why don't you do it on each click? It is no heavy process and doesn't seem to require http calls or so on. Looks like premature optimization.

Comment: Let me rephrase, if user clicks once and after 500 ms the function is called should be made, but before that if user clicks then he should be allowed update quantity and after 500ms then functions is called.

Comment: @Amy yes you are correct, i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Witch method do you want to be called once after user finished the clicking?

The fastest way you can resolve this is if you use mouseleave, mouseout, touchleave events. What means your user has moved his mouse off the interactive area of an element. (in your case he stops clicking and he moves his mouse out) so you can update your price "**once**"

More info about events you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/Events).